# How does a web server know the incoming HTTP request is dynamic or static?

Tags: http, httprequest

Apologies if this is a silly question, I am new to HTTP requests.

I have this quote from MDN - source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Client-Server_overview

> After the coach submits the form with the team name and number of players, the sequence of operations is:
>
> 1. The web browser creates an HTTP GET request to the server using the base URL for the resource (/best) and encoding the team and player number either as URL parameters (e.g. /best?team=my_team_name&show=11) or as part of the URL pattern (e.g. /best/my_team_name/11/). A GET request is used because the request is only fetching data (not modifying data).
> 2. The Web Server detects that the request is "dynamic"

how does the web server detect the browser is dynamic?

As I read that both static and dynamic websites use exactly the same communication protocol/patterns. How does the web server detect that the request is dynamic?

Comment: The answer is right there in the same sentence - `the web server determines how to handle different URLs based on pattern matching rules defined in its configuration`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distinction between "static" and "dynamic" isn't an attribute of the request, or even really of the response, it's just a description of *how the server chooses to generate the response*.

In a "static" web server, the incoming URL is mapped to a file path on a local disk, and the response is created based on the contents of that file. In a "dynamic" web server, the incoming URL is processed in some other way, and the response is generated according to more complicated logic. There are many different ways that could be done, and many grey areas in between - the URL could be processed with some simple string replacements and *then* the result looked up on disk, or the "dynamic" logic could check some authentication information and then return the same content a "static" web server would, etc.

So the server doesn't "detect that the request is dynamic", it applies a set of configuration rules, and decides what to do - respond with the content of a file, run a particular program, return a hard-coded error page, etc. It's just a convenient shorthand to refer to the common case of "map to a file path and respond with the content of that file" as "static", and the other extreme of "run a particular program" as "dynamic".